# Native base ListItem renders empty view?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am writing a very simple view with native-base.

When I did this in my render() function

```
  <Container>
    <Content>
      <List>
        <ListItem>
          <Text> text1 </Text>
          <Text> text2 </Text>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </Content>
  </Container>
```

I notice that nativebase renders me a completely empty list item.

But if I remove one of the Text tag. The item will show up properly.

So is it impossible to have more than 1 children for a listItem? that seems really counter intuitive. What should I do to have more than 1 item for a list item in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: NativeBase List]

Here is the working example of something that you need.

```
<Container>
  <Content>
    <List>
      <ListItem>
        <Text> text1 </Text>
        <Text> text2 </Text>
      </ListItem>
    </List>
  </Content>
</Container>
```

This also works well

Comment: This is very weird. I will probably update my native-base. Your code does not work in my project. I notice that i must wrap the view under a <View> tag

Comment: Yes try updating NativeBase to latest 0.5.18